# Бесконечное нажатия правой кнопки мыши и под лаг игры

Tags: python

```
import keyboard
import mouse

activate = True
while activate:
     if keyboard.is_pressed("i"):
        mouse.click('right')
```

Здравствуйте, написал такой код для кс го, хотел сделать нажатия пкм.

Через кнопку на клавиатуре i просто для теста, так вот при нажатии на i правая кнопка не просто нажимается, а бесконечно.

Для теста я взял нож и нож бил вечно а не раз как я хотел
также с авиком, он бесконечно щёлкает зум.

И второе это при каждом нажатии на i игра на доли секунд замирает до того как начинает бесконечно нажиматься пкм.

Так же если удержать кнопку i примерно на секунд 10 то игра крашиться.

Скажите как можно сделать чтобы не было таких проблем, можно было задать определённое количество нажатий на мышь и ещё чтобы нажатия были только в кс го.